# How to remove broken cleanout cover

Tags: plumbing

Hi have a broken cleanout cover that needs to be replace any ideas on how to remove it? Thanks[image]

Comment: how did you remove it before it broke

Comment: Just hope a previous DIY "expert" didn't glue the cover in place... I had to demo a concrete floor once to get enough access around the pipe to be able to cleanly cut it of low enough to build it back up with a very short extension pipe and a new cover. What should have been a 5-minute job to replace the cover turned into 2 Saturdays, before I had new concrete poured and re-tiled the floor.

Answer (score 8):

Unscrew it, or break it more and pry it out of the threads.

Obviously, you'll need to use something like locking pliers to grab on to the remains of the top to unscrew it. Once clamped on you could tap (not bash) with a hammer to get it moving - if you bash, you'll probably just break the plastic where the locking pliers are grabbed on, now move the whole thing towards unscrewing.

It would also help if you first removed all the stray dirt and grit that will help to bind the threads.

Comment: The dirt and grit won't bind the threads as you remove it - the motion will clear the threads naturally!

Comment: @MikeBrockington not so much. If you don't remove it, it keeps using gravity to drop into the next thread and grind that as soon as it "clears" the one it's in. It's well worth the (small amount of) time to wash and/or vacuum that out of there as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could also get a strip of wood similar to a paint stirrer and screw or clamp it to both sides of the top, where there's the most edging on each side. Then use the strip of wood as a handle and turn counterclockwise. Spray the top with water to clean out the cracks and all that dirt.